# Transparent CSS gradient around circular image background

Tags: html, css, effect

I keep trying to accomplish a transparent gradient effect (thinking about white) around an image background, absolutely positioned maybe?, you can imagine what I'm talking about seing my explanatory paint.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create radial gradients in css with the `radial-gradient` function and make your elements rounded with `border-radius`.

```css
.transparent-gradient {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.transparent-gradient img {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.transparent-gradient::after {
  content: "";
  background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(255,255,255,0) 0%,rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="transparent-gradient">
  <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1530279281203-4c60af01ee58?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&s=02b66d237286bcb2a071ed6c1e72adf3&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" width="400">
</div>
```